# Android NDK API list?

Tags: android, api, android-ndk

Is there a way/tool to enumerate all the C function prototypes (not sure if that's the right term) from the .h files in the NDK folder subdirectories (i.e. C:\android-ndk-r8b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include) and produce something like a javadoc?  The reason I'm asking is because we have a developer on our end who is trying to port his Windows code over to the android platform and before he begins to go forward with such an effort, he needs to know what API calls are supported so he can begin changing his code base to make it Android-NDK compliant.  I've run across the following links in my search for an answer:

```
http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#c++
C:/android-ndk-r8b/docs/STABLE-APIS.html
C:/android-ndk-r8b/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to check if the code is compliant is to compile it and see what breaks. Win32 API surely would - there's even no point in checking if an NDK counterpart exists. The C/C++ RTL is a little more tricky - some functions have counterparts, some don't. But enumerating them all and matching by hand is, frankly, a waste of time. A compiler will do the same much faster.

Comment: Is there at least a document somewhere on the internet that lists all available C++ functions that the NDK supports?  The documentation that comes with the NDK itself is really sparse.

Comment: No. And for a reason, too. Because there are C RTL functions, C++ RTL functions, Linux syscalls, Android specific functions, functions in optional libraries - and all those are documented independently.

Comment: Can those be found in the NDK?  I must've missed something.

Comment: They're *supported* by the NDK, but not *documented* in the NDK. Because some come from Linux kernel and are documented in Linux manpages, some from GNU C and are documented at GNU.org, some from Android itself. Only the latter are documented with the NDK, but you already found those docs. Look, what exactly is the problem? Give us some specifics.

Comment: My co-worker is trying to make his C++ code written on the Windows platform as platform-independent as possible and needs a full list of C++ functions, which include pThreads, Sockets, and the C++ RTL, that will work on Android (and iOS later on, but just Android for now).

Comment: They are all documented, but not in one single place. Besides, it's not just functions - the compilers (assuming he's using MSVC) differ, too. Until you actually compile for Android, you'll never know if it's compatible. Trust me, I've been there.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, let the code be Linux compliant. The minute differences between Android libs and Linux can usually be resolved incrementally. Note that you have a moving target here: platform-14 supports much more Linux headers than 9.

Comment: I did a search this morning and stumbled upon: http://cgi.cs.indiana.edu/~nhusted/dokuwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:android_project_documentation.pdf, which contains a list of C functions that are supported by Linux libc but not Android libc. Do you think this is a good place to start?

Comment: Not exactly. This document refers to Android v. 2.3.4, but today the system is at 4.1.2. Many functions have been exposed since then. On the other hand, most of the Android devices _out there in the wild_ are 2.3.x, and it is always a hard decision to choose the level of backwards compatibility of your app.

Comment: Been look all over Google for the past hour and still haven't found a list of supported C library functions for Android's bionic. :\

Comment: That's exactly what I've been telling you from the start, isn't it?

Comment: Guess I'm giving him the bad news then.

Comment: Luckily, sockets and pthreads (the latter not to full extent) are supported.

Comment: See the answer on [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/tree/browse_frm/thread/d0dacd67a64879db/020fd72199c4f3af) as the closest to an official statement on the matter as could possibly be.

Comment: Ok thanks.  One of the other answerers had mentioned using the Linux command line tool "nm -D" to list symbols in the libs.  If I used this tool on libc.so, would that give me at least a list of C standard library functions on Android>

Comment: "nm -D" on /system/lib/libc.so only gives you the list for one specific version on one specific device. You can look into ndk/platform/include for the list of officially supported APIs for each platform.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tenouk.com/Module000linuxnm3.html

can you use libs instead of .h files?

the link explains using 'nm' to dump symbols from libs